# Массивы Delphi

Tags: массивы, delphi

```
program Project4_3;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  SysUtils;
var
a:array [1..3, 1..4] of real;
i,j:integer;
s,s1:real;
begin
for i:=1 to 3 do
for j:=1 to 4 do
readln (a[i,j]);

end.
```

Как вычислить для каждой строки этого двумерного массива 
сумму значений элементов строки и как присвоить вычисленным значениям сумм 
элементам одномерного массива соответствующей длины?

Comment: @Luchfan12, Согласно правилам форума, вопросы не должны сводиться к решению либо завершению учебных заданий за учащихся. Пожалуйста, уточните, что вы сделали сами и что не получилось.

Comment: Напишите формулу вычисления для каждый строки двумерного массива суммы значений элементов строки

Comment: @Luchfan12 больше не отвечаю на твои вопросы, я от них минусы получаю.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
program Project4_3;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  SysUtils;
var
  a:array [1..3, 1..4] of real;
  b:array [1..3] of real;
  i,j:integer;
  s,s1:real;
begin
  for i:=Low(a) to High(a) do begin
    s:=0;
    for j:=Low(a[i]) to High(a[i]) do begin
      readln (a[i,j]);
      s:=s+a[i,j];
    end;
    b[i]:=s;
  end;
end.
```

Comment: Спасибо!А как вычислить для каждой строки этого двумерного массива среднего значения элементов строки и как присвоить вычисленным средним значениям элементам еще одномерного массива соответствующей длины?

Comment: на основании уже предоставленного кода можно это сделать

Comment: окей,попробую